# Intuition behind the solutions of the Schrodinger equations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I am learning the basic and easy first examples of the most common problems in Quantum Mechanics,and while trying to find solution to the Schrodinger equation,i find myself struggling with the intuition behind finding the general solution of the equation.

The lecturer sometimes writes that the solution is of form $A\sin x+B\cos x$ and sometimes he writes $Ae^{ip/h}+Be^{-ip/h}$ and sometimes he writes $Ae^{p/h}+Be^{-p/h}$.

Now i know that the first two general solutions are connected via Euler's formulas so i suspect that whichever i write down i will get the right solution.
But,the question is about all three general solutions(i know that afterwards there might be more general solutions as these are for simple cases-or not),so i want to know if there is something that intuitively tells you which one you have to choose in order to start solving the equation.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to solve an ODE of the form $\ddot{x}=\pm\omega^2x$? How does the $\pm$ change the solution?

Comment: Yes i know how to solve ODE.But the lecturer has most of the times got a ODE of the same form but in each case he solves them in a different manner.So it must be that something physical shows him to solve it in the way that he does.

Comment: Well, for one: the $\pm$ sign.

Comment: Maybe I'm being a bit pedantious, but your question is not about "the Schrödinger equation", but about "the Schrödinger equation with certain potential $V(x)$" (I guess that a square potential well/barrier). You should post your hamiltonian to make the question clearer

Comment: @KyleKanos yes this is true.Anything else?

Comment: @Bosoneando i do not know about Hamiltonians yet.Yes,most problems have to do with the square potential well.

Comment: You are using the hamiltonian in the Schrödinger equation, even if you don't know it :). Anyway, you should post the equation(s) that troubles you.

Comment: Well,i am talking about multiple occasions here,so i don't think that this would be practical

Comment: How do you expect to get help with some specific equations if you don't show us those equations? I think that your question is basically "Why do I get different solutions, one with real exponentials and other with imaginary exponentials?" If this is your question, the answer is: "Because you're solving different equations!"

Comment: Yes,but what things in a problem tell us which solution to use?I mean,there must be some physical meaning for using imaginary exponentials and another for real ones.

Comment: The potential $V(x)$. As a general rule, if the energy is less than the potential, the wavefunction will vanish exponentially (i.e., you have to use the real exponential) while if the energy is greater you'll have the oscillatory solutions. Anyway, you'll (hopefully) see everything clearer when you learn what a hamiltonian is.

Comment: Another way to think about it, is to allow the parameters $p$ to be any complex number, then you will get an algebraic equation from subjecting your exponential ansatz to the equation, which you can solve (and which will tell you, whether $p$ is imaginary or real).

Comment: @SebastianRiese i didn't understand

Comment: The way you solve this type of Schrödinger equation is by ansatz. You know that something of the form $Ae^{px}$ solves the equation, by plugging this form in the equation, you get an algebraic equation for $p$, and this equation tells you, whether $p$ is real or imaginary. Then you have to put together the solutions on the different domains, such they are continuously differentiable (otherwise there would have to be a $\delta$-peak in the potential) and the result is normalizable.